# Сборка QT под Android в cmd (Windows)

Tags: c++, qt

Как я могу собрать QT проект в .apk файл не используя QT Creator? То есть через командную строку.

Версия QT - 5.12.2, Windows 10

Чем и каким образом собирать разницы не имеет, лишь бы работало.

Заранее спасибо.

UPD:

1.

```
D:\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe D:\QT\untitled\untitled.pro -spec android-clang "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
Info: creating stash file D:\QT\untitled\.qmake.stash
```

2. 

```
D:\programs\SDK2\ndk\19.2.5345600\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe -f D:/QT/untitled/Makefile qmake_all
make: Nothing to be done for `qmake_all'.
```

3. 

```
D:\programs\SDK2\ndk\19.2.5345600\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe -j8
D:/and/and/tools/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain D:/and/and/tools/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sysroot -isystem D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sources/android/support/include -isystem D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -g -g -marm -O0 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtQuick -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtGui -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtQml -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtNetwork -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I. -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang -o main.obj main.cpp
D:\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\bin\rcc.exe -name qml qml.qrc -o qrc_qml.cpp
D:/and/and/tools/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain D:/and/and/tools/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sysroot -isystem D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sources/android/support/include -isystem D:/and/and/tools/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -g -g -marm -O0 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtQuick -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtGui -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtQml -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtNetwork -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I. -I..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang -o qrc_qml.obj qrc_qml.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from ..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtGui\QGuiApplication:1:
In file included from ..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtGui/qguiapplication.h:43:
In file included from ..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:43:
..\..\programs\QT\5.12.2\android_armv7\include\QtCore/qglobal.h:45:12: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
#  include <type_traits>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [main.obj] Error 1
```

Comment: Стандартный ход: qmake, make - пробовали?

Comment: @gbg, благодарю за ответ, пробовал. Постоянно возникают какие-то ошибки, может быть есть какое-нибудь руководство?

Comment: Действия довольно прозрачны - нужно разбираться с ошибками

Comment: @gbg, обновил вопрос. Команды брал из лога сборки QT Creator'ом (QT Creator собирает без проблем)

Comment: Все проблемы в путях к нужным заголовкам и файлам